# Convert to excel with , present in the field

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am passing some of the field from apex to excel, However for the records having , in between it is assigning the value on right to the field in next column. Is there anyway to take comma into consideration and replacing it in a way that it doesnt append in next column.

Example : ABCV , Inc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the each values in double quotes?

```
"value1, something", "value2", "ABCV , Inc."
```

---

Tried following page:

```
<apex:page contentType="text/csv#test.csv">"a, b", c</apex:page>
```

In CSV, I get two columns `a, b` and `c` as desired.

Comment: Its still not working ,  if(os.Opportunity__r.name.contains(','))
                        {
                        inputOppName='"'+os.Opportunity__r.name+'"';
                        Opps = Opps + ' ' +inputOppName;
                        }

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the latest code? I’ll give it a try!

Comment: checked it works for me. not sure what you're doing is cause the problem.